# Is it better to have more bundles or one for JS and one for CSS in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

I am not really sure if having more bundles is better or having one bundle for javascript and one for css is better. Can anyone explain the better approch.

Comment: Multiple bundles are allowed, but never mix between JS & CSS files to avoid hassles. The bundling principle is one bundle name is dedicated to one kind of file type, not for both.

Comment: Yes.. I understand that.. they will either have javascript or stylesheets.. but is it better to have more bundles or less.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That largely depends.  If you have a particular javascript file that changes frequently, you might want to have that be in a separate bundle, while scripts that change infrequently should go into a single bundle.

The same with CSS.  You can bundle stuff like bootstrap, jqueryui, etc.. css into a single bundle, but leave your own css in a separate one, because it will change less frequently, and thus not require downloading all the unchanged code.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest for the less bundle because as per msdn its says

[**MSDN:**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification) Bundling is a new feature in ASP.NET 4.5 that makes it easy to combine or bundle multiple files into a single file

It shows  that  bundling itself will make multiple files into a single file.

So In general ,I will prefer one entry for one kind of file, mostly you will have only two entries in RegisterBundles() method,that is one for js and another one for css to the entire project.

This is my preference and suggestion

hope it was helpful to you

Thanks

Karthik